# how can I choose an array based on user input?

Tags: java, arrays, math, types

I'd be really grateful for any help here.

I'm trying to code a program that reads a given amount of positive numbers after each other then adds, subtracts, multiplies, calculate the average them with each other.

I know how to code the operations, just I don't know how to read the user input.

1. My program asks the user initially how many number he she is going to type in, and based on that I want to code my program in such a way that it creates an array that matches the size and data types of the user input.

I'm struggling with arrays, and would really appreciate any help whatsoever. Here's how it should function briefly:

1. Ask for user input.
2. Read the input
3. Create an array based on the input (based on data type and amount of numbers)
4. Proceed with the various arithmetic operations.

I hope I can find some help here.
Thanks in advance, Charmaine!

here is my code so far, with comments stating where exactly i need help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Amount of numbers "); //I need to code an array based on this answer
    double zahl1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Type in the numbers "); // also how can I save n amount of numbers the user gives?
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        double summe = (zahl1 + zahl2 + zahl3); //I know how to code the rest just not with an unknown amount of number, this is with two numbers
        double durchschnitt = ((summe)/3);
        double produkt = zahl1 * zahl2 * zahl3;
        double Kleinste; if (zahl1 < zahl2) {
                            if (zahl1 < zahl3) {System.out.println( zahl1 + " ist die Kleinste");}
                            else {System.out.println(zahl3 + "ist die kleinste");}
                            }
                          else {
                            if(zahl2 < zahl3){System.out.println(zahl2 + " ist die Kleinste");}
                            else System.out.println(zahl3 + " ist die Kleinste");
                          }
        double Größte; if (zahl1 > zahl2) {
            if (zahl1 > zahl3) {System.out.println( zahl1 + " ist die Größte");}
            else {System.out.println(zahl3 + "ist die Größte");}
            }
          else {
            if(zahl2 > zahl3){System.out.println(zahl2 + " ist die Größte");}
            else System.out.println(zahl3 + " ist die Größte");
          }
    System.out.println("Die Summe betraegt " + summe);  
    System.out.println("Der Durchschnitt betraegt " + durchschnitt);    
    System.out.println("Das Produkt ist " + produkt);

    }    

}
```

Comment: You've got the steps outlined for you, and you should try to solve each step one at a time, even in isolation if tough, and then put it all together. You should try something really before coming here, if only to help you focus your question a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! Please check the code I've posted, maybe you can help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure how to begin, just try to write the code in the order of the steps you need to take. Ask for the input, (I imagine you mean prompting the user, which you could just do with a System.out.println() statement), and then actually reading the input, using something like the Scanner class. There are several different ways to handle the array. If you're not sure how to begin, the least frustrating way to handle the arithmetic would just be a series of if-else statements. This is the kind of thing that's more helpful to figure out on your own, rather than having someone else give you code that you don't understand how to use.

Comment: I've figured out the arithmetic more or less, just how I can use the scanner to read n amount of numbers, and save them in an array, which i can later use in the arithmetic.

Comment: Instantiate a Scanner object like so: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in), and use the Scanner method nextInt() to actually read in the input.

Comment: I have just that in my code (see original post) but how does this work when multiple inputs should be read after the each other? Then saved in an array? I'm lost for ideas..

Comment: Are the numbers they're inputting being inputted individually? eg the user hits enter every time they type a number? Or are the numbers being inputted all at once, separated by spaces, or commas or something?

Comment: Either or is fine, thought I think I prefer individual inputs.

Comment: if they're being inputted individually, (what I'd find easier), you can do a for loop like this:   for ( int i = 0; i < zahl1; i++ ) { array[ i ] = scan.nextInt() }     I think zahl1 is the int you use to store the number of numbers they input. One more thing, I'm not sure why you declare scan twice.

Comment: yes that's right. So far so good, but now I have the problem that all numbers are saved as zahl1. I need to calculate the sum, which isn't possible with my above code since I only have one variable i.e.zahl1. Would you be explain how I can do my arithmetic with "just" zahl1?

Comment: all the numbers you have are saved in the array. The only number zahl1 saves is the number of inputs you're going to get, which basically determines the length of your array. The array itself holds all the numbers. If you want to get the sum of all the numbers the user inputs, you could use another for loop, and use the index of the array. Instantiate an int to represent the total, and then add all the values of the array to total. So    for ( int i = 0; i < zahl1; i++ ) { total = total + array[ i ] }             The operation with total can be shortened to: total += array[ i ]

Comment: I'm having a problem initialising the array, as I obviously can't use "null". What initial value should I assign to the int array?

Comment: Don't you get the user to input the number of numbers he is adding in with the line 'System.out.println("Amount of numbers ");'? Create the array based on that number should work fine.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. What Foleosy said is correct.

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Amount of numbers "); //I need to code an array based on this answer
  double anzahl = scan.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Type in the numbers "); // also how can I save n amount of numbers the user gives?
  
   for ( int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++ ) { int[] array = anzahl;
    array[ i ] = scan.nextInt() ;
    }
  
         int summe = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++ ) { int[] array;
   summe = summe + array[ i ] ; } 

That's an extract of the problematic code , can you maybe decipher the problem or what I should change?

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" number of numbers to be processed please:"); //asks for the total number of numbers that will be inputted.
    int totalNum = scan.nextInt(); //stores the number of numbers to be processed in totalNum

     array = new int[totalNum]; //creates an array, called array, of size totalNum; the number of numbers to be processed is the size of the array.

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = scan.nextInt(); //fills the array with the numbers that the user inputs. 
    }            I hope you can read that

Comment: But why can't totalNum array be resolved to a variable? I'm just very confused atm..

Comment: because it is an array. Each element (like array[ 1 ], array [ 2 ], array [ 0 ], etc) holds a different value.

Comment: So how do I resolve this?  can't compile the code otherwise:
totalNum array = new int[totalNum]; //that's where the problem is

Comment: totalNum isn't your array. totalNum is the size of the array. Your array is called array, in the code I posted. You could call whatever you want, but I'm calling it array for recognition purposes. You can't declare totalNum as an array, because it's an int. Your array is completely different. It uses totalNum to determine how large the array is going to be.

Comment: Aah, thanks a lot. I've figured it out now!
Have a good Saturday!

Answer (score 0):

This should fill your array for you. I hope its clear enough. If any problems arise with my array declaration, check out this place:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

I hope this is helpful.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" number of numbers to be processed please:"); //asks for the total number of numbers that will be inputed.
int totalNum = scan.nextInt(); //stores the number of numbers to be processed in the int totalNum

array = new int[totalNum]; //creates an array, called array, of size totalNum; the number of numbers to be processed is the size of the array.

for ( int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ )
{
    array[i] = scan.nextInt(); //fills the array with the numbers that the user inputs. 
}
```